# Barcodes in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am currently running SSRS 2012 and am wanting to implement barcodes in to one of my reports, I have read numerous things on the net about the number of issues people have while trying to do this so though I would post here and try to avoid the pitfalls.

As I said I have SSRS 2012 installed and I also have a number of Barcode TTF files that we needed to use for something else.  My questions are can this be used to convert my *0100415332* in to a barcode that is able to be scanned? and where do I need to put these files, I have read that they need to go in to C:\Windows\Fonts on the client machine but where on the Server side?

After that I believe that you are able to change the font of the relevant text field within the report that contains the barcode and have something that is converted and able to be scanned.

Any assistance is where I might be going wrong or what else I might need to do before embarking on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks P

Comment: Is it an option to use an assembly generating an image instead of using a TTF font?

Comment: what barcode format are you using? code39? code 128?
different barcode formats need different start stop characters.

Comment: I used '3of9' font in one of my reports - it seemed to largely depend on the reader and the quality of the printer as to whether the barcode could be read or not. Also i was more successful when exporting to PDF and printing from that, as opposed to printing direct from IE.

Comment: @PJD did you ever resolve this. I have same issue

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a simple install of the barcode font on the server that you're planning on using.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/font-installation-and-deletion

Also, while code3of9 is an easy barcode to manage, it is susceptible to errors, since it has no checksum.  Your barcode can be damaged and return a value that's different than what it should be.  With a barcode font that uses a checksum, such as Code128, if what the barcode reads as doesn't match the checksum, the bar code won't be  read.  I would strongly recommend using Code128 with the following function to return the barcode with it's checksum.

```
Public Function GetBarCode(InString as string)
Dim nSum As Decimal, i As Decimal, checkdigit as Decimal
Dim Checksum As Decimal, Checkchar As Decimal
Dim MyString As String, CVal As Decimal, sValues as string

sValues = "ä!" + chr(34) + "#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍ"
' Initialize running total with value of Subset B start character
nSum = 104

' Scan the string and add character value times position
For i = 1 To Len(InString) Step 1    
    MyString = Mid(InString, i, 1)
    ' Get the numeric value of the character and subtract 32 to shift (the space character, ASCII value 32, has a numeric value of 0 as far as Code 128 is concerned)
    CVal = instr(svalues,mystring)-1
    ' Add the weighted value into the running sum
    nSum = nSum + (CVal * i)
Next i
' Calculate the Modulo 103 checksum
Checksum = nSum Mod 103
if checksum = 0 then checksum = 174
' Now format the final output string: start character, data, check character, and stop character
MyString = "{" +  InString + right(left(sValues,Checksum),1) + "~"
MyString = Replace (MyString," ", "ä")
GetBarCode = MyString

End Function
```